# Can I toast pecans the night before?

Tags: baking, nuts, toasting, pecan

I'm making pecan bars in the morning and I was thinking I'd get a jump on the work by toasting the nuts tonight. Is there a downside to toasting the pecans and then letting them sit overnight vs toasting them tomorrow and tossing them right into the recipe?

Comment: I'd just make sure to seal them afterwards to keep them dry.. jar or sealable bag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, no problem with that at all. Toast away!

Answer (score 2):

You can toast them and keep them for much longer than one day if you wish.

Comment: Yep. Whaddya think, about a month for maximum quality? I'd add a time frame to my answer if I really knew how long. I know that stores sell perfectly good toasted nuts in the bulk aisle (so no airtight packaging).

Comment: I've kept roasted nuts for up to a month but why would you want to? Eat them if they're good. Anyways, roasted nuts will keep for longer than un-roasted, since the moisture is removed / reduced.